# Is it better to use a TreeSet or ArrayList when using a custom comparator

Tags: java, performance, sorting, arraylist, set

I have implemented a graph.
I want to sort a given subset of vertices with respect to their degrees. 
Therefore, I've written a custom comparator named `DegreeComparator`.

```
private class DegreeComparator implements Comparator<Integer>
{
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer arg0, Integer arg1) 
    {
        if(adj[arg1].size() == adj[arg0].size()) return arg1 - arg0;
        else return adj[arg1].size() - adj[arg0].size());
    }

}
```

So, which one of the below is more efficient?

**Using `TreeSet`**

```
public Collection<Integer> sort(Collection<Integer> unsorted)
{
    Set<Integer> sorted = new TreeSet<Integer>(new DegreeComparator());
    sorted.addAll(unsorted);
    return sorted;
}
```

**Using `ArrayList`**

```
Collections.sort(unsorted, new DegreeComparator());
```

Notice that the second approach is not a function, but a one-line code.

Intuitively, I'd rather choose the second one. But I'm not sure if it is more efficient.

Comment: If you're worried about speed, avoid boxing `int`s into `Integer`s.

Comment: Takes less time and space given the fixed input size. Time is prior to space.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

[image]
Java API contains numerous Collection and Map implementations so it might be confusing to figure out which one to use. Here is a quick flowchart that might help with choosing from the most common implementations

Comment: I'm missing `LinkedList`, `Queue`s/`Deque`s, `Concurrent*`, `Blocking*` and `*SkipList`s

Comment: This chart fails for anything you want sorted for e.g. display (e.g. it's not about searching). It also doesn't actually answer the original question, which was about performance, not which type of collection to choose.

Answer (score 10):

A TreeSet is a Set. It removes duplicates (elements with the same degree). So both aren't equivalent.

Anyway, if what you want naturally is a sorted list, then sort the list. This will work whether the collection has duplicates or not, and even if it has the same complexity (O(n*log(n)) as populating a TreeSet, it is probably faster (because it just has to move elements in an array, instead of having to create lots of tree nodes).

Comment: So, I should slightly modify the comparator. Please see my edit for my modification.

Comment: @OnurÇağırıcı TreeSet will still remove duplicates, I assume that is by design ??

Comment: @PeterLawrey How does new modification remove the duplicates? I don't have two vertices with same ID. If their connectivities are the same, it is going to return the difference between IDs.

Comment: @OnurÇağırıcı You didn't state that you wouldn't have duplicate values.  If you don't have duplicates, there is no duplicates to remove.  In the ArrayList it won't remove duplicates even if you had them.  ArrayList is faster, so this might be in your favour.

Comment: **They're equivalent in a case like the OP described** (20 minutes after your answer).

Comment: @maaartinus: that proves my point: with a TreeSet, you have to write your comparator so that it makes sure no object is equal to any other object. That's a predictible source of bug, and it's not trivial to implement if the objects don't have an ID.

Comment: @JBNizet I never said, you were wrong. You're right, it's just that the requirements changed. For id-less objects, there's a universal solution (see my answer).

Answer (score 3):

If you only sort once, then the `ArrayList` is an obvious winner. The `TreeSet` is better if you add or remove items often as sorting a list again and again would be slow.

Note also that all tree structures need more memory and memory access indirection which makes them slower.

---

If case of medium sized lists, which change rather frequently by a single element, the fastest solution might be using `ArrayList` and inserting into the proper position (obviously assuming the arrays get sorted initially).

You'd need to determine the insert position via `Arrays.binarySearch` and insert or remove. Actually, I would't do it, unless the performance were really critical and a benchmark would show it helps. It gets slow when the list get really big and the gain is limited as Java uses [TimSort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort), which is optimized for such a case.

---

As pointed in a comment, assuring that the `Comparator` returns different values is sometimes non-trivial. Fortunately, there's Guava's [`Ordering#arbitrary`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#arbitrary()), which solves the problem if you don't need to be compatible with `equals`. In case you do, a similar method can be written (I'm sure I could find it somewhere if requested).

Comment: The lists are dynamic. Actually, there are two disjoint lists and I am adding a vertex to one while removing the same from the other.

Comment: @OnurÇağırıcı This makes then sort of dynamic if you're doing it often. If the lists are less than 100 elements and you're not doing it more than 100 times per second, you needn't care. You the [root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)?

Comment: Sadly, no, my lists are over 1000 elements and I don't know how many times I'm doing it but clearly it is more than 100 times.

Comment: @OnurÇağırıcı Then it *might* make sense to optimize it. Or not, I'd suggest to benchmark it before you start optimizing too much. I'll post another idea in about one hour.