# Java - Which collection suits this situation best in terms of performance?

Tags: java, performance, collections, arraylist, set

I'm writing a class that needs to read strings from a file and store them in some data structure. What should I use given the following:

- The file will contain up to several hundreds of strings (they need to be stored in a structure, can't stream).
- The entries need to be stored in a specific order.
- Once sorted the collection will not be modified (It doesn't have to be immutable, but I know it won't be modified).
- I will need to iterate through the collection several times.
- If there are duplicate entries in the set, only one of them should be stored.

The following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24371204/is-it-better-to-use-a-treeset-or-arraylist-when-using-a-custom-comparator/24371582#24371582) (and others) say that an ArrayList is better if I only need to sort once since it reads faster, but if I use an ArrayList then I will have to make sure they are unique manually.

Comment: You could always place them in a `Set` initially, which won't allow duplicates, and then move them to an ArrayList to use thereafter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html). It is a set, so it will not store duplicate entries. It sorts the entries directly when inserting. The basic operations require `log(n)` time. Thus, the overall time requirement is similar to inserting into a list first and then using a `n*log(n)` sorting algorithm.

Comment: A single access to a random element of a TreeSet will have O(log n) complexity - which is worse than accessing an element from an ArrayList with O(1). However, when iterating, the overall complexity should be better (ideally O(n) for the whole iteration process). This assumes that the Iterator implementation is clever enough to not start searching from the top of the tree again for every single next() call. However, I did not find any statement concerning this matter in the TreeSet JavaDocs.

Answer (score 2):

I did a little benchmark of TreeSet vs ArrayList insertion/performance. Obviously ArrayList performs the better but, with a million unique records 279ms of full iteration time is not that bad.

If in your case that time is negligible i'd stick with the TreeSet. Otherwise you'll be forced to reivent the wheel and to manually check for duplicates before inserting the element into the ArrayList.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class TestTreeSetVsArrayList {
    public static int ENTRIES = 10000000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeSet<String> treeSet = new TreeSet<String>();
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(10000);
        long l = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < TestTreeSetVsArrayList.ENTRIES; i++) {
            treeSet.add("String"+i);
        }
        System.out.println("treeset insertion time: "+ (System.currentTimeMillis()-l));
        l = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < TestTreeSetVsArrayList.ENTRIES; i++) {
            treeSet.add("String"+i);
        }
        System.out.println("arraylist insertion time: "+ (System.currentTimeMillis()-l));

        Iterator<String> iter;
        iter = treeSet.iterator();
        l = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while(iter.hasNext()) {
            iter.next();
        }
        System.out.println("treeset iteration time: "+ (System.currentTimeMillis()-l));

        iter = arrayList.iterator();
        l = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while(iter.hasNext()) {
            iter.next();
        }
        System.out.println("arraylist iteration time: "+ (System.currentTimeMillis()-l));

    }

}
```

The results on my pc are:

> treeset insertion time: 11350
>
> arraylist insertion time: 3583
>
> treeset iteration time: 279
>
> arraylist iteration time: 0

Answer (score 1):

If you can sort the elements while inserting, consider a TreeSet (if necessary with a self-defined Comparator).
If not, it seems you might need two structures:

1. An ArrayList for initial filling and sorting.
2. Afterwards, a LinkedHashSet in order to ensure singularity while preserving order.

Comment: What advantages would LinkedHashSet give me in terms of iterating through the collection compared to the ArrayList?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use a [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html), which is a:

`Hash table and linked list implementation of the Set interface, with predictable iteration order`

...

`This implementation spares its clients from the unspecified, generally chaotic ordering provided by HashSet, without incurring the increased cost associated with TreeSet.`

Answer (score 0):

If you can sort at any time: Insert the strings to a `Set` (preferably `HashSet`, I presume), and then spill them into an `ArrayList` and sort.

Comment: Given that TreeSet sorts them at insertion, isn't it faster than sorting the ArrayList?

Comment: It depends on whether you want the original sorting ciretiria. If so, you are probably right. Note that ArrayList has better locality than other collection, hence the sorting should be somewhat faster.